# Как в Python циклически брать по 4 элемента и добавлять их в другой массив

Tags: python-3.x

у меня есть массив A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 , 11, 12]

мне нужен цикл что бы каждые 4 элемента массива были добавлены в массив B, так что бы массив B был B = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]

Comment: Срочно читать про срезы списков!

Answer (score 2):

```py
B = [A[i : i + 4] for i in range(0, len(A), 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 , 11, 12]
B = []
k = 0

for i in range(len(A)//4):
  B.append([j for j in A[k:k+4]])
  k += 4
print(B)
```